# Should i use ajax or node fs module to read json files and write json

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

When using json data to store say quiz questions should i use vanilla ajax or node js file system  read file?

I am going to build  a site where users can create quizes and save as json. I want  to use node fs module to save the array of questions as json but when reading the file for the quiz should i use ajax or node js fs read?

Also can my site users save files written to the vps server?

Comment: Yeah, just use vanilla.

Comment: Possibly both Ajax and `fs`, as they don't serve the same purpose and aren't mutually exclusive. Ajax allows communication between a web client and web application server, and that server (if defined in Node.js) could use the `fs` module to write the information from the client to the file system.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is a method for data transfer between a client and a server, while node's fs module is for parsing a file. If you're saving a json files to persist data, you would need to use the fs module to read that file. Vanilla AJAX to read a file doesn't make sense, you're conflating different technologies.

You could use AJAX to transmit data between the client and the server, and then use node's fs module to write a json file to disk to persist the client's payload.